# Autosomal Dominant Polycystic Kidney & Liver Disease

Tags: liver, swelling, kidney-stones, urination

My Mother is having ADPKD in both kidney and liver. Is there any medicine for this disease. Over the time, the liver has swelled a bit and the bulge is quite visible.

I recently took her to doctor and he just asked if she is facing any problem while urination and some other normal questions. He also said we have to wait and watch.

I want to know what all care should be taken to either get cured from this disease or to prevent it from increasing.

After some research on internet, I found that this disease is incurable. Is there some research going on or any successful results shown up in near past?